# R - Accessing .Traceback from the base environment in a custom error handler

Tags: r, error-handling

I am writing a custom error handler (using the `error` option) that is primarily intended to be used with programs run with `source`. In the custom error handler, I would like to compute the line number(s) of the file being sources that caused the error.

Normally, whenever an error is thrown, `.Traceback` in the base environment is modified to include the call stack that caused the error. In addition, calls that were present directly in the source file are given an attribute of class `srcref` that contains information regarding the location of the call in the file.

However, it seems that `.Traceback` is not set until after the custom error handler has concluded, meaning that I cannot rely on it to find the line numbers of the code causing the error.

Is there any way to get the same information that `traceback` produces while inside a custom error handler? I know that I can do `sys.calls` to get the call stack but this won't include the information about the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Warning* section in `?traceback` says, "It is undocumented where `.Traceback` is stored nor that it is visible, and this is subject to change." So you shouldn't rely on that variable.  Instead, you should do what `?traceback` suggests (and provides and example of) and call it with an integer count of calls to skip.

```
foo <- function(x) { print(1); bar(2) }
bar <- function(x) { x + a.variable.which.does.not.exist }
foo(2) # gives a strange error
# [1] 1
# Error in bar(2) : object 'a.variable.which.does.not.exist' not found

# This will print the stack trace at the time of the error.
options(error = function() traceback(2))
foo(2)
# [1] 1
# Error in bar(2) : object 'a.variable.which.does.not.exist' not found
# 2: bar(2) at #1
# 1: foo(2)
```